# Jquery limit user upload to 5 posts every minute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have got this jquery/ajax

```
var uploaded=0;
if (uploaded!=0) {   
    setInterval(function() {
        uploaded--;
    }, 60000);
    alert(uploaded);
}
$(".UploadMSub").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_data = new FormData($('.SubmUploadFu')[0]);
    if (uploaded<=5) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../connect.php',
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,                         
            success: function(data)
            {
                var json_x = $.parseJSON(data);
                var classRes = json_x[0].substring(0, 1);
                $(".Result").html(json_x[0]).addClass(classRes).fadeIn(500).delay(2500).fadeOut(500,function() {
                    $(this).removeClass(classRes);
                });                
                $(".Posts").children(".NumberOf").html(json_x[1]);
                $(".Text").val("");
                $("#Nameupload").val("");
                $(".PhotShow").slideUp(500);
                uploaded++;
            }
        });
    }else{
        $(".Result").html("You can upload up to 5 posts in one minute").addClass("E").fadeIn(500).delay(2500).fadeOut(500);                 
    }

});
```

And this php

```
function isFileUploadAllowed() {
    $isAllowed                  = true;
    $timeNow                    = time();
    $timeFrameInSeconds         = 30;
    $maxUploadsInTimeFrame      = 5;
    $firstUploadTime            = $_SESSION['firstUploadTime'] ? intval($_SESSION['firstUploadTime']) : $timeNow;
    $numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame = $_SESSION['numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame'] ? intval($_SESSION['numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame']) : 0;
    $givenTimeFrameExpired      = (($firstUploadTime + $timeFrameInSeconds) < $timeNow);
    if (!$givenTimeFrameExpired) {
        if ($numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame + 1 > $maxUploadsInTimeFrame) {
            $isAllowed = false;
        }
    }

    if ($isAllowed === true) {
        if ($givenTimeFrameExpired) {
            $_SESSION['firstUploadTime'] = $timeNow;
            $_SESSION['numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame'] = 0;
        }

        $_SESSION['numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame']++;
    }
    return $isAllowed;
}       

if(isset($_POST['new_post'])){
    $Text=htmlspecialchars($_POST['new_post'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $Text=trim($Text);
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['Upload_f']['tmp_name'])) {
        if (isFileUploadAllowed()) {
            $fileP=$_FILES['Upload_f'];
            $fileP_name=$fileP['name'];
            $fileP_tmp=$fileP['tmp_name'];
            $fileP_size=$fileP['size'];
            $fileP_error=$fileP['error'];
            $fileP_extension=explode('.', $fileP_name);
            $fileP_extension=strtolower(end($fileP_extension));
            $allowed=array('jpg','png');
            if (in_array($fileP_extension, $allowed)){
                if ($fileP_error===0) {
                    if ($fileP_size<=2097152){
                        $fileP_new_name=uniqid().'.'.$fileP_extension;  
                    }
                }
                $NotInarray=false;
            }else{
                $fileP_new_name="";  
                $NotInarray=true;
            }
            $Fileuploaded=true;
        }
    }else{
        $fileP_new_name="";
        $fileP=0;
        $Fileuploaded=false;
        $NotInarray=false;
    }
    $Posts=$con->query("SELECT Posts FROM user_opt WHERE Username='$NameId'");
    $row=$Posts->fetch_row();
    if (strlen($Text)>400) {
        $Res="Error occurred.Please try again";
        $PostNum=$row[0];
    }elseif(strlen($Text)==0 && $fileP==0){
        $Res="Both fields are empty";
        $PostNum=$row[0];
    }elseif($Fileuploaded===true){
        if ($NotInarray==true) {
            $Res="Only jpg and png files are allowed";
            $PostNum=$row[0];
        }elseif ($fileP_error!=0) {
            $Res="Error occurred.Please try again";
            $PostNum=$row[0];
        }else{
            $Res="Success";
            $PostNum=$row[0]+1;
        }
    }else{
        $Rand=generateRandomString(100);
        $query=$con->query("INSERT INTO uploads (Rand,Username,image,`Text`,`Date`) VALUES('$Rand','$NameId','$fileP_new_name','$Text',NOW())");
        $querya=$con->query("UPDATE user_opt SET posts=posts+1 WHERE Username='$NameId'");
        $PostNum=$row[0]+1;
        $Res="Success";           
    }
    echo json_encode(array($Res,$PostNum));
}
```

But the problem is when user uses dev tools he can easily change

```
if (uploaded<=5) {
```

To

```
if (uploaded<=50) {
```

And jquery will take increase limit to 50.How can i prevent that?
Also may the problem be in php function?Cause if my php function works properly it should not insert data into database but it does

Comment: Check it on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no `else` clause for `if (isFileUploadAllowed())`, so you're not clearing the variables. You can combine that test with the outer test:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['Upload_f']['tmp_name'] && isFileUploadAllowed())
```

Comment: It is still possible to change if (uploaded<=5) { to if (uploaded<=51) {

Comment: So? Nothing you do in the Javascript affects the PHP code on the server.

Comment: You should **never** rely on client-side validation or authentication checks. If there's anything you can't allow the user to bypass, it must be done on the server.

Comment: Yes my question is how can i write the same js code in php.Cause as u said user can easily change client-side code.

Comment: Isn't that what `isFileUploadAllowed` already does? I thought you were just saying that it's not working correctly.

Comment: And that's what my answer is supposed to fix. It's still not working?

Comment: Do you call `session_start()` in the PHP script before trying to use the session variables?

Comment: I forgot to assign value to $_SESSION['numberOfUploadsInTimeFrame'] in my main file.My bad.